# Django : reference to models in view --> Local variable might be referenced before assigment

Tags: python, django

I have a small Django-app were I want to manage two stock portfolios. I created two tables (SecuritiesSVR and SecuritiesAHT) with the same structure (based on an abstract model). In the url I added an argument 'ptf' : portfolio/str:ptf/change_position

Now I want to access these two tables via a view as underneath:

```
@login_required
    def change_position(request, ptf, symbol):
        if ptf == 'aht':
            Securities = SecuritiesAHT
        if ptf == 'svr':
            Securities = SecuritiesSVR
        security = Securities.objects.get(pk=symbol)
       ...
```

In PyCharm I get a warning on my variable Securities : "Local variable might be referenced before assigment'. However, the view seems to work correctly. Does anyone know why I get this warning?

Answer (score 1):

You see this warning because in case when `ptf` variable's value is not `'aht'` and not `'svr` code blocks in both if statements will not be triggered and `Security` variable will not be defined. To remove this warning, you can add additional block to return error response.

```
@login_required
def change_position(request, ptf, symbol):
    if ptf == 'aht':
        Securities = SecuritiesAHT
    elif ptf == 'svr':
        Securities = SecuritiesSVR
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('not valid ptf')
    security = Securities.objects.get(pk=symbol)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because if none of your conditions are true then the line `security = Securities.objects.get(pk=symbol)` will raise an error because you didn't define `Securities` variable and your Pycharm gives you that warning. If you're sure that every time at least one of your conditions will check you can get rid of this warning by doing something like:

```
@login_required
    def change_position(request, ptf, symbol):
        Securities = None
        if ptf == 'aht':
            Securities = SecuritiesAHT
        if ptf == 'svr':
            Securities = SecuritiesSVR
        security = Securities.objects.get(pk=symbol)
```

or you can set another default value like:

```
@login_required
    def change_position(request, ptf, symbol):
        Securities = SecuritiesAHT
        if ptf == 'aht':
            Securities = SecuritiesAHT
        if ptf == 'svr':
            Securities = SecuritiesSVR
        security = Securities.objects.get(pk=symbol)
       ...
```